# Running install command in CMake, but only if

Tags: cmake

I am extremely new to CMake, and having trouble setting up an install rule.
I want to run the following command in `make install`:

```
update-rc.d solshare_stats_runscript defaults
```

But I only want to run this command if:

```
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably do this using [`install(SCRIPT ...)`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3ainstall) and provide a wee CMake script to be invoked.

So add this to your CMakeLists.txt:

```
install(SCRIPT InstallScript.cmake)
```

Then in the InstallScript.cmake:

```
if("${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}" STREQUAL "/")
  execute_process(COMMAND update-rc.d solshare_stats_runscript defaults
                  RESULT_VARIABLE Result
                  OUTPUT_VARIABLE Output
                  ERROR_VARIABLE Error)
  if(Result EQUAL 0)
    message(STATUS "Ran update-rc.d as CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX == \"/\"")
  else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Result - ${Result}\nOutput - ${Output}\nError - Error")
  endif()
else()
  message(STATUS "Not running update-rc.d as CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX != \"/\"")
endif()
```

You may need to provide more arguments to the [`execute_process`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3aexecute_process) call in the script (e.g. `WORKING_DIRECTORY`).

Comment: First of all: thank you very much. Second: the script has one issue: it does not know the variable ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}: ` if given arguments:

    "STREQUAL" "/"

  Unknown arguments specified
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake_install.cmake:60 (INCLUDE)


make: *** [install] Error 1
`

Comment: I got that fixed by moving the check to the CMakeLists.txt file. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad you got it fixed.  Another alternative is to wrap the `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` inside the `if` with quotes (as I've now done).  Cheers.

Comment: @Fraser I am impressed by your knowledge of CMake... Are you among the developers?

Comment: @Antonio Thanks for the compliment, but no, I'm not a Kitware dev.  I'm not sure how many Kitware folks are on here, but [Bill Hoffman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/216085/bill-hoffman) and [Robert Maynard](http://stackoverflow.com/users/95496/robertjmaynard) are Kitware, and until recently, so was [David Cole](http://stackoverflow.com/users/236192/dlrdave).

Comment: Does this have any effect on what make package produces?  Specifically with the DEB and RPM generators.